# Pandas dataframe rows won't drop

Tags: python, pandas, string

**Background -** I am trying to drop rows from a pandas dataframe (`exceptions_df`) if all 3x conditions are met.

**Conditions -**

1. `Ownership Audit Note` column value contains partial string values of either `ignore` or `Ignore`.
2. `Entity ID %` column value is == `Account # %` (this column is formatted as a `float64`).
3. `% Ownership` coumn is == `100`. (this column is formatted as a `float64`)

**Extract from dataframe -**

```
  % Ownership     Ownership Audit Note       Entity ID %     Account # %  
0 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    0.0000000       0.0000000  
1 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    0.0000000       0.0000000  
2 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    0.0000000       0.0000000  
3 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    0.0000000       0.0000000    
4 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    0.0000000       0.0000000    
5 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    1.0000000       1.0000000  
8 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    0.0000234       0.0000234  
9 100.00          [ignore] 100% Ownership    0.0000000       0.0000000
```

**My code -**

```
exceptions_df = exceptions_df[~exceptions_df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore'|'Ignore') & 
                             [~exceptions_df['% Ownership'] == 100] & 
                             [~exceptions_df['Account # %'] == 'Entity ID %']]
```

**Issue -** I seem to be getting the following `TypeError:`, which is referencing the above line of code. Have I missed something obvious? Strangely if I just include the first condition / first line of code, then it works fine!

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please add sample df, with the sample, there is room to improve your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove inside quotes in .contains(). Made dummy df for example.

```
exceptions_dict = {'% Ownership': {0: 100.0,
  1: 100.0,
  2: 100.0,
  3: 100.0,
  4: 100.0,
  5: 100.0,
  6: 100.0,
  7: 100.0,
  8: 90.0,
  9: 100.0},
 'Ownership Audit Note': {0: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  1: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  2: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  3: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  4: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  5: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  6: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  7: '[ignore] 100% Ownership',
  8: 'foo',
  9: 'foo'},
 'Entity ID %': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 1.0,
  6: 2.34e-05,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 1.0,
  9: 1.0},
 'Account # %': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 1.0,
  6: 2.34e-05,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 2.0,
  9: 2.0}}

exceptions_df = pd.DataFrame(exceptions_dict)

exceptions_df = exceptions_df[(~(exceptions_df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore|Ignore'))) & 
                                (~(exceptions_df['% Ownership'] == 100.0)) & 
                                (~(exceptions_df['Account # %'] == 'Entity ID %'))]

print(exceptions_df)

    % Ownership Ownership Audit Note    Entity ID % Account # %
8   90.0        foo                     1.0       2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of wrong partition brackets. Lets try

```
exceptions_df = exceptions_df[(~(exceptions_df['Ownership Audit Note'].str.contains('ignore'|'Ignore'))) & 
                             (~(exceptions_df['% Ownership'] == 100)) & 
                            ( ~(exceptions_df['Account # %'] == 'Entity ID %'))]
```